# How to extract text/tweet from Riak Object? (erlang)

Tags: json, twitter, erlang, riak

I've stored some thousand tweets in my Riak Node and fetching one of them returns the following:

```
{riakc_obj,<<"tweets">>,<<"529940801938542592">>,
           <<107,206,97,96,96,96,204,96,202,5,82,28,202,156,255,126,
             134,152,237,143,206,96,74,...>>,
           [{{dict,2,16,16,8,80,48,
                   {[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],...},
                   {{[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],...}}},
           <<"{\"created_at\":\"Wed Nov 05 10:18:27 +0000 
             2014\",\"id\":529940801938542592,\"id_s"...>>}],
           undefined,undefined}}
```

I'm confused now though, how can I extract the actual information from the object? Since I'm fetching tweets, these come with a lot of unnecessary information besides the actual "text" that the user wrote. Is it possible to somehow reduce the value of a Riak Object into a string?

Not sure if this was clear enough, I'll elaborate if needed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just use [`riakc_obj:get_value/1` function](http://basho.github.io/riak-erlang-client/riakc_obj.html#get_value-1).

As I from data you provided, actual text is represented as binary string ([`<<102,...>>`](http://www.erlang.org/doc/programming_examples/bit_syntax.html)). While shell sometimes have some issues with printing it, you are still able to just pass it to any IO (file, socket), or do any operations you would like.

Comment: Thanks, easier than I thought.. Any clue how to get out the information after "text"? get_value/1 returned:

 "<<"{\"created_at\":\"Wed Nov 05 10:18:27 +0000 2014\",\"id\":529940801938542592,\"id_str\":\"529940801938542592\",\"text\":\"RT @gar"...>>

Comment: Is it JSON? There is [jsx](https://github.com/talentdeficit/jsx) which works quite nice. Or [jiffy](https://github.com/davisp/jiffy).